# AWS and cron job: improve logging, monitoring and concurrence

Tags: design, logging, aws, cron, monitoring

In my company, we use a separate cron server to run mission-critical background jobs that run on a single ec2 instance: the whole platform is then vulnerable to anything going wrong on this instance.

We want to change the design of the system.

Based on that, I need to modify the system in order to make it more reliable. Here are some issues and needs we have:

- no way to see if some cron runs stall on something
- setup a cron job status tracking system
- jobs cannot be run concurrently
- deploys cannot be canceled or reverted

My first thought here is to move the cron from EC2 to [EventBridge Scheduler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/what-is-scheduler.html) because EBS provides Retries, and then we can minimize the stalls. To properly monitor the system I want to suggest Datadog.
Then use [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) for not concurrently jobs.
[Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html) for the deployment.

I usually work as a developer, and in my previous experience we had a DevOps team in charge of the infrastructure, but in my current experience, the company asks everyone to be involved in everything... I am confused because from what I learned on AWS, there are a few ways to implement this scenario. For example, I can use Lambda, or maybe create another EC2 on another AZ, but this is the first time I am in charge of designing and implementing the architecture.

May I have another point of view, please?

Comment: "some jobs cannot be run concurrently" is the reason for this interdependency?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about the details of the cron jobs functionalities and their interdependencies, it seems that you'd benefit from implementing a data pipeline, a saga pattern or combination of both.

Saga Pattern
[image]

Data Pipeline

[image]